# Deselect word after Define in UITextView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview, uimenucontroller

I've got a `UIViewController` with `UITextView` in its view. When user selects text, there's *Define* system menu item that uses `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` to define the word. The problem is that the word stays selected after the dictionary is dismissed. I'd prefer it to be deselected (like it's done in iBooks).

I've tried to deselect the word using `UIMenuControllerDidHideMenuNotification`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIMenuControllerDidHideMenuNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification) {
    [textView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];
}];
```

This deselects the word but also freezes my `UIViewController` with the following message:

```
2012-12-20 19:18:45.553 Pilcrow[7018:c07] Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <_UIFallbackPresentationViewController: 0x75b8300> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!
2012-12-20 19:18:45.963 Pilcrow[7018:c07] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <_UIFallbackPresentationViewController: 0x75b8300>.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: and it is not freezed, if you remove your selection code? I guess, that you have another problem..? Just comment out the line you showed us and try it again.

Comment: Nope. When I don't do `setSelectedRange`, everything works well.

Comment: Have you tried to call it on the main thread explicitly? e.g. dispatch_async on dispatch_get_main_queue()

Comment: Nope. Can you provide me with a concrete code, please?

Comment: BTW, I've just tried `performSelectorOnMainThread:` and still the same. :(

Answer (score 0):

The dismissal probably takes around 0.25-0.33 seconds. So how about doing a `performSelectorAfterDelay` or `dispatch-after` after this duration?

Comment: Might be, but it could still be before the end of he animation block or run loop. Also there are cases when the didHide fires too early.